# Flink is not writing all records in kafka topic partitions

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have my Flink job which is writing data to Kafka topic in 3 partitions.
Using IDE it is writing all data I can see them in the topic but while running it on **cluster** some of the records are missing.
It is not writing all data.

Comment: Please tell us which Kafka connector you are using (the FlinkKafkaProducer or the KafkaSink), which version, and how it is configured. Do you have checkpointing enabled? Did you terminate the job that produces the records that are missing; if so, how? How did you detect that records are missing? Might you have had transactions that timed out?

Comment: I am using Cloudera Flink-Kafka connector Flink version is 1.12-csa1.4.1.0 I am using FlinkKafkaProducer I know for the new version FlinkKafkaProducer is deprecated but this is not an issue for me.
Yes I do have checkpointing enabled at every 3 seconds and set the mode to exactly_once max concurrency for the checkpoint is 1, I set checkpoint timeout for 50 seconds and also I made retain on cancellation.
I did not set an exception how can I detect missing records I am checking it in kafka topic and that data is important for 2nd job to trigger.